# Adding tags to an org file

Tags: org-tags

I had the following tags for a given file.

```
#+TAGS: @Completed(c) @Doubts(d) @Discuss(D) @Not_Implemented(n) @KR28(R28) @KR29(R29)
```

I added the last two tags today and they did not get populated when I pressed `C-c C-q`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I read through the [org documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html#fn-1) and found that the user had to keep cursor on the `#+TAGS:` line and  press `C-c C-c` in order to update the local setup.

**Quote from the org manual**

> Don't forget to press C-c C-c with the cursor in one of these lines to activate any changes.

After pressing `C-c C-c` - org mode will give a message like

> Local setup has been refreshed

**Tag shortcut**
The other thing that the user should keep in mind is that, one is not allowed to use more than one characters within the parenthesis.

For example: `@KR28(R28)` would not work as `R28` is present within the parenthesis. This should be either one letter or one number.

Also, if the *user does not define a shortcut* for a particular tag, org by itself will assign a shortcut for that tag. (*Citations required - if available*)